# Could not add system.web.routing in class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, class-library, system.web.routing

I want to create a class library for an MVC 4 web application.I created class library project in same solution and write classes and other stuff in class library.I added the reference System .Web.Routing in my class library project. But when i tried to use
System.Web.Routing in project that displays following error

The type or namespace Routing does not exist in the namespace System.Web

How to add this in my class library project?

Comment: Have you a reference to System.Web.dll?

Comment: Check the project properties and make sure the .NET 4 Framework Client Profile isn't selected. Use .NET 4 Framework profile instead